# installed specific version of hdf5(1.8.16) mac

Tags: macos, hdf5

I want to install hdf5 with a specific version: 1.8.16, but with the command, brew install hdf5, I got the newest version, 1.8.17, can you help me, I checked out some similar solutions, it does work.

Comment: The method that people talked about like this:brew tap homebrew/boneyard  , brew versions hdf5, this does not work anymore with the newest version of brew, Error: The `versions` command is no longer supported.
You can use the homebrew-versions tap instead:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions
Or use `brew log` to browse the git history.,   So do we have any solutions right now????

Comment: http://effectif.com/mac-os-x/installing-specific-version-of-homebrew-formula this doesnt work

Comment: brew tap homebrew/versions this doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

1. [Download](https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles-science/) your OS-specific hdf5-1.8.16.tar.gz

   - [hdf5-1.8.16.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz](https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles-science/hdf5-1.8.16.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz)
   - [hdf5-1.8.16.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz](https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles-science/hdf5-1.8.16.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz)
   - [hdf5-1.8.16.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz](https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles-science/hdf5-1.8.16.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz)
2. Extract
3. `mv hdf5 /usr/local/Cellar/`
4. `brew link hdf5`

Comment: This is assuming you `brew uninstall hdf5` any previous hdf5 installed through brew.

Comment: First link is dead